# Validation in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, validation

I need to check whether all fields are filled while clicking insert button.
This is my view:

```
<body>

    <form name="form1">
        <h2>MEDICATION</h2>
        <div class="med">
            <pre>        
 <label>Patient code</label>       <input type="text" id="pat" name="ptcode" size="25" value="" />                                <label>ICD10</label>  <input style="width:85px;height:30px;" type="text" name="icd10" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button style="height:30px;width:59px;" name="search" onclick="openicd()";>search</button><br />
<label>Medication</label>         @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.medication, Model.medication,"Select Medication", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })   <button style="height:30px;"onclick="openmedication()";>search</button>            Prescription Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value="">

<label>Strength</label>           @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.strength, Model.strength, "Select Strength", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })                    Start Date         <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value="">   End Date  <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><br />                        
<label>Form</label>               @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.form, Model.form, "Select form", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })                    Renewal Date       <input type="date" class="sizetestdate" name="testdate" style="width:140px;height:30px;" value=""><label> Days Supply</label> <input type="text" style="width:85px;height:30px;" name="supply" value="">  <br />         
<label>Route</label>              @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.route, Model.route, "Select route", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })                    <label>Pharmacy</label>           @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.pharmacy, Model.pharmacy, "Select Pharmacy", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })<br />                    
<label>Dose</label>               @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.dosage, Model.dosage, "Select Dose", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px" })                    
</pre>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="button" style="height:30px;" id="a" >Insert</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="button" style="height:30px;" id="b">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="button" style="height:30px;" id="c">Delete</button>

    </div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your model for validation

```
public class Example {

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

[view more - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
The best way is adding model Validations in Models 
i don't know how your model look like assuming

public class Meditation 
{
  [Required]
  public int id{get;set}

  [Required]
  public int name{get;set;}



}
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; should be added 

or you can simply use required in form 

<input type="text" style="width:85px;height:30px;" name="supply" value="" required>

  @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.dosage, Model.dosage, "Select Dose", new { style = "width:200px; height :30px", @required="true"})
```